# MySQL Subquery from ASC order to DESC order

Tags: mysql

```
select *, sum(sales_qty) as total_qty 
 from sales_details 
 left join sales on sales.salesid=sales_details.salesid
where month(sales.sales_date)='$m'
group by productid order by total_qty asc limit 2, 4
```

I have that sql that is sorted in ascending order. Now I want the results to be sorted in descending order. I have tried using subquery but doesn't work for me. Any help or suggestion is appreciated.

This is the sql that I have tried:

```
select * from (
      select *, sum(sales_qty) as total_qty
        from sales_details
        left join sales on sales.salesid=sales_details.salesid
       where month(sales.sales_date)='$m'
       group by productid
       order by total_qty asc 
       limit 2, 4
     ) as sub 
 order by sum(sales_qty) desc
```

Comment: Why not just replace the `asc` keyword with `desc`?

Comment: I have first sorted it in asc to get the least 4 total_qty now I want the result to be sorted in desc order.

Comment: Spotting the problem in your query required a long-distance scroll to the right, which makes it hard for SO volunteers to spot. I reformatted your queries to contain line breaks. It's generally a good idea to format SQL queries for readability.

Answer (score 1):

Your query with the subquery should end

```
 ... ORDER BY sales_qty DESC
```

Why? When you say `... ORDER BY SUM(sales_qty) DESC` you're converting the *outer* query into an aggregate query.  Because that outer aggregate query has no `GROUP BY` clause, it necessarily has a one row result set.

The outer query treats the inner query *as if it were a table, a virtual table*. That virtual table has a column named `sales_qty`. It is the value by which you want to order.

Pro tip:  Don't use `SELECT *` in aggregate queries. You're misusing the notorious nonstandard MySQL extension to `GROUP BY`, which means your result set contains unpredictable values. Read this. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html